# Bash find file with specific permission for group, no matter permission for user and others

Tags: bash, find

Using only octal notation, I need to find file that have only read permissions for group, no matter which owner and other permission are.

Which is the right command? I can't find it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [find(1) manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) says it all :

```
   -perm -mode
          All of the permission bits mode are set for the file.
          Symbolic modes are accepted in this form, and this is usually
          the way in which would want to use them.  You must specify
          `u', `g' or `o' if you use a symbolic mode.   See the EXAMPLES
          section for some illustrative examples.

   -perm /mode
          Any of the permission bits mode are set for the file.
          Symbolic modes are accepted in this form.  You must specify
          `u', `g' or `o' if you use a symbolic mode.  See the EXAMPLES
          section for some illustrative examples.  If no permission bits
          in mode are set, this test matches any file (the idea here is
          to be consistent with the behaviour of -perm -000).

   -perm +mode
          This is no longer supported (and has been deprecated since
          2005).  Use -perm /mode instead.

   -readable
          Matches files which are readable.  This takes into account
          access control lists and other permissions artefacts which the
          -perm test ignores.  This test makes use of the access(2)
          system call, and so can be fooled by NFS servers which do UID
          mapping (or root-squashing), since many systems implement
          access(2) in the client's kernel and so cannot make use of the
          UID mapping information held on the server.
```

I will not put the plain answer here, because frankly 
this is an easy thing to figure out.